# Polymorphic function for Print & reverse Print in C++ within a single class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have written two methods for printing my linked list data. One is print which works normally. And one is for printing the list in reverse order. I want to make my print method to accept a `Node* ptr` and do the rest of the work as usual. I'm not getting the idea how to make it work because of the operator overloading. My methods are as follows. Please ignore the void* casting and return in the `reversePrint` method.

```
template <class T>
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& str, LinkedList<T> const& data){
        data.print(str);
        return str;
    }

    template <class T>
    void LinkedList<T>::print(std::ostream& str) const{
        Node *curr = head;
        while(curr != nullptr){
            str << curr->data << "\n";
            curr = curr->next;
        }

    }

    template <class T>
    void* LinkedList<T>::printReverse(std::ostream& str) {
        Node* curr = head;
        //Node* last = (Node*)getLastNode(head);
        Node* rHead = nullptr;

        while(curr != nullptr){
            Node* temp = curr->next;
            curr->next = rHead;
            rHead = curr;
            curr = temp;
        }

        while(rHead != nullptr){
                std::cout << rHead->data << "\n";
                rHead = rHead->next;
            }
        return (void*)rHead; 
    }
```

class definition.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList {

private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *next;

        Node(T data, Node *next) :
                data(data), next(next) {
        }

    };
    Node* head;

public:
    LinkedList() :
            head(nullptr) {
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        Node *temp;
        for (; head; head = temp) {
            temp = head->next;
            std::cout << "Destructor called for " << temp->data;
            delete head;
            }
    }

    void append(T item);
    void insert_at_head(T value);
    void* getLastNode(Node* n);
    void print(std::ostream& str = std::cout) const;
    void* printReverse(std::ostream& str = std::cout);

};
```

Comment: `Node` most probably needs to be templated as well.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is a `struct` as a private member of the `class LinkedList` I do not see any particular use of it that's why keep it straight  just as a data holder.

Comment: You haven't actually given enough information.   How do you expect to call the various functions?   Is the `print()` that accepts a `Node *` intended to be a member of `LinkedList<T>` or not?   Is `Node` a templated class?   How is the presence of a `printReverse()` function even relevant to your problem (I suspect it is not)?

Comment: @Peter `printReverse` will not go anywhere but it will become only reverse and the rest of the work will be done by the `print` `Node` definition is included in the function, Please have a look. I want one single method only which will be `print` I want it to accept a `Node*` which could be any node from list and print it onward by traversing the list.

Comment: _"I want to make my print method to accept a Node* ptr"_ I don't understand what you want to have. Could you write a (probably not working) version of what you are trying to do? Maybe as pseudo code...

Comment: "please ignore" - no, please don't ignore broken things. Just fix them. It's _your_ code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it already is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printReverse` probably should **not** modify the list.

I would write it recursively. Idea:

```
template <class T> void LinkedList<T>::printReverse(std::ostream &str, Node const* head) {
    if (!head) return;
    printReverse(str, head->next);
    std::cout << head->data << "\n";
}
```

With e.g. declarations in-class:

```
    void printReverse(std::ostream &str) const { printReverse(str, head); }
  private:
    void static printReverse(std::ostream &str, Node const* head);
```

---

Off-topic:

- consider const-correctness
- consider Command/Query Separation (separate node iteration from printing)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93d52133eb8fa43e)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T> class LinkedList {

  private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *next;
        //Node(T data, Node *next) : data(data), next(next) {}
    };
    Node *head;

  public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

    ~LinkedList() {
        while (head) {
            Node* temp = head->next;
            std::cout << "Destructor called for " << head->data;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

    void append(T item) {
        Node* t = getLastNode(head);
        (t?t->next : head) = new Node { item, nullptr };
    }

    void insert_at_head(T value);

    Node const*getLastNode(Node const*n) const {
        for (Node const* it = n; it; it = it->next)
            if (!it->next) return it;
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node*getLastNode(Node*n) {
        for (Node* it = n; it; it = it->next)
            if (!it->next) return it;
        return nullptr;
    }

    void print(std::ostream &str = std::cout) const;
    void printReverse(std::ostream &str) const { printReverse(str, head); }
  private:
    void static printReverse(std::ostream &str, Node const* head);
};

template <class T> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &str, LinkedList<T> const &data) {
    data.print(str);
    return str;
}

template <class T> void LinkedList<T>::print(std::ostream &str) const {
    for (Node const* curr=head; curr; curr = curr->next) {
        str << curr->data << "\n";
    }
}

template <class T> void LinkedList<T>::printReverse(std::ostream &str, Node const* head) {
    if (!head) return;
    printReverse(str, head->next);
    std::cout << head->data << "\n";
}

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> ll;
    ll.append(1);
    ll.append(2);
    ll.append(3);
    ll.append(4);

    ll.print(std::cout);
    ll.printReverse(std::cout);
}
```

Prints

```
1
2
3
4
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think I do not make it clear enough what I actually want from `print` & `printReverse` methods. I want `printReverse` to reverse the list and return a pointer which will be the head ptr of the reversed list. And `print` will then accept that ptr as param and will print the contents. So that I can use the `print` for any kind of output that this list going to generate.

Comment: Addressing the off-topic notes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e987f4fa9d189f16

Comment: @Superman to the comment: that's very very bad naming then. Split the logic indeed. You want to in-place reverse the list (?!) or create a copy?

Comment: No I don't want to reverse in-place. Just a traversal and this will be just another pointer which will be the head of the reversed ptr.

Comment: Here's the power of Command/Query separation: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/924753a844a110df (copies reverse to a list of `double` and prints that)

Comment: @Superman do you realize how bad of an idea that is? Who _owns_ that pointer? (hint: nobody knows, so you were going to leak the memory)

Comment: I'm sorry for it. But you might have already a good idea that I'm a beginner and just learning the C++. Your every comment and versions of code are great. And I'm thankful to you for providing very good coaching on each aspect. Definitely I'm trying to make things work just, but you considering the design and re-usability of code for later.

Comment: I'm afraid to use `const` and operator overloading. I started from Java and now C++ OOP is too alien to me. virtual methods, destructors with and without virtual and references and const references which I think is already constant but still at many places const is used along with reference. Within the param list and outside the methods. Gosh. Bjarne Stroutstrup make it too difficult :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94320/discussion-between-sehe-and-superman).

Comment: Code isn't working on eclipse with gcc C++ 11. Lots of errors, looks like nothing is supported by the compiler you used in the code. :(

Comment: Huh. You mean, you mean, by the compiler you used in Eclipse? Are you sure (a) it doesn't compile (if Eclipse gives warnings, doesn't mean it's not compiling) (b) it's configured to compile in c++11 mode?